# Sqlite table creation does not allow to create table

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_IMG + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + KEY_IMAGE_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PATH + " TEXT" + ")";


    final String CREATE_TAG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TAG + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + KEY_TAG_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TAG_DATE + " INTEGER" + ")";



   final String CREATE_IMGTAG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_IMAGE_TAG + "("  + TAG_ID            + " TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_TAG (tag_id)," + IMG_ID + " TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_IMG (img_id),"
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER, " + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY(IMG_ID,TAG_ID,KEY_ID)" + ")";



    db.execSQL(CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TAG_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_IMAGE_TAG_TABLE);

    Log.i("TAG", "TABLES CREATED" + CREATE_IMAGE_TAG_TABLE);
}
```

Hello All

I am trying to create 3 tables with image data, tag data and 3rd having the id's of image and tag data into it. I want to create 3rd table with the references of image table's Id and tag table's Id which are both primary key's in their own table. Now if i want to add id's values of these tables into my third table i have fired the query as above but it does not let me create it. It gives me syntax error:

```
09-10 14:52:13.741: E/Database(9850): Failure 1 (near "(": syntax error) on 0x223a80 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE img_tag_table(tag_id TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_TAG (tag_id),img_id TEXT REFERENCES TABLE_IMG (img_id),id INTEGER, INTEGER PRIMARY KEY(IMG_ID,TAG_ID,KEY_ID))'.
```

Comment: Check the third Create table query its of that

Comment: Are you sure that all varaibles have been replaced correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what `CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE(id)` is supposed to do, but I think it should be `" + TABLE_IMG + "(" + KEY_ID + ")`

Comment: You have a missing bracket at the end

Comment: My error is coming for the third table creation other 2 tables get created perfectly fine

Comment: Can you please post hier the plain query from the third Create table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `img_tag PRIMARY KEY (IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID)`

This column specification gives you the syntax error on `(`. What are you trying to achieve?

If you want to make `IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID` pairs unique/primary keys, just change it to a table constraint

```
PRIMARY KEY (IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID)
```

In your code:

```
final String CREATE_IMAGE_TAG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_IMAGE_TAG + "("
        + IMAGE_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE(id)," + TAG_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES CREATE_TAG_TABLE(id),"
        + " PRIMARY KEY (IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID) " + ")";
```

---

After your edited question the problem is:

> `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY(IMG_ID,TAG_ID,KEY_ID)`

This is neither a column specification or a table constraint. To make it a table constraint, remove the `INTEGER` (code as above). To make an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, change it to something like `columnname INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you meant something like this.

```
final String CREATE_IMAGE_TAG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_IMAGE_TAG + "("
            + IMAGE_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES " +  TABLE_IMG + "(id)," + TAG_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TABLE_TAG + "(id),"
            + IMG_TAG + " PRIMARY KEY (IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID) " + ")";
```